# Graphviz - how to space out self-referencing edges to avoid making a visual mess?

Tags: graphviz

I have a graph where instances of objects sometimes call themselves.  This is using the **dot** layout engine.

```
digraph G {

  foo;

  foo -> foo [label="msg1"];
  foo -> foo [label="msg2"];
  foo -> foo [label="msg3"];

}
```

That's making somewhat of mess in the rendered graph because they all end up at the same spot.

[image]

What's the easiest/best way to space them out a bit?  I suppose a brute force approach is to add hidden nodes `n1, n2, n3` and then `foo -> n1; n1->foo; foo -> n2;...`

I am probably looking at the order of 7-8 self-referencing messages per node, max, but a solution for 3-4 would be a good start.

[online viewer/editor](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20G%20%7B%20%20foo%3B%20%20%20%20foo%20-%3E%20foo%20[label%3D%22msg1%22]%3B%20%20foo%20-%3E%20foo%20[label%3D%22msg2%22]%3B%20%20foo%20-%3E%20foo%20[label%3D%22msg3%22]%3B%7D)

This is a stab at the hidden nodes approach. Not great either.  Removing the `label` attribute on the invisible nodes still left a gap between arrows.

```
digraph G {

  foo;
  foo -> n1 [label="msg1" dir="none"];
  n1 -> foo;
  foo -> n2 [label="msg2" dir="none"];
  n2 -> foo;
  foo -> n3 [label="msg3" dir="none"];
  n3 -> foo;
  n1 [ label = "", style = invis ];
  n2 [ label = "", style = invis ];
  n3 [ label = "", style = invis ];
}
```

[image]

Best I have managed so far (actual edge labels are pretty long so I've added that to see results) is by using n1, n2, n3 intermediary nodes, not hidden, but using `shape="plaintext"`:

```
digraph G {


  foo;
  foo -> n1 [dir="none"];
  n1 -> foo;
  foo -> n2 [dir="none"];
  n2 -> foo;
  foo -> n3 [dir="none"];
  n3 -> foo;
  n1 [ shape="plaintext" label="msg111111111111111111111111111"];
  n2 [ shape="plaintext" label="msg222222222222222222222222222" ];
  n3 [ shape="plaintext" label="msg333333333333333333333333333" ];

}
```

giving:

[image]

**Edit:**  Looking for answers relevant to **dot** as I sometimes pass the DOTs to specialized rendering libraries like [d3-graphviz](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz), I know that works with **dot**, not sure about other layout engines.

Comment: You can force some separation between your self-edges by giving each one a different, explicit port direction at both ends: `foo:n -> foo:n`, `foo:ne -> foo:ne`, and so on.  The results still aren't great, I'm afraid.

Comment: @jasonharper  thanks for the suggestion, but, yes, they remained somewhat of a mess, not so much wrt the edge arrows, which do get spaced, as the edge labels, which do not do so consistently.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with **dot** or **neato**

```
digraph G {
  graph [center=true pad=.5]

 subgraph clustera {
  // neato seems to ignore margin!
  graph [margin=70 style=dotted] // change dotted to invis for finished graph
  graph [nodesep=.3] // neato, not dot
  // edge[labelangle=0 labeldistance=4] // minlen=.7]

  foo [height=.8 width=1.4 shape=circle];

  foo -> foo [tailport=n  headport=n    taillabel="msg1"];
  foo -> foo [tailport=ne  headport=ne  taillabel="msg1a"];
  foo -> foo [tailport=e  headport=e    taillabel="msg2"];
  foo -> foo [tailport=se  headport=se  taillabel="msg2a"];
  foo -> foo [tailport=s  headport=s    taillabel="msg3"];
  foo -> foo [tailport=sw  headport=sw  taillabel="msg3a"];
  foo -> foo [tailport=w  headport=w    taillabel="msg4"];
  foo -> foo [tailport=nw  headport=nw  taillabel="msg4a"];
 }
}
```

[dot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k0RC.png)

Comment: I like it, I'll see if I can get it working on my actual code though.